# Prove $\lim_{x \to 0^-} \frac{\sqrt{x^2}}{x}=-1$

Tags: analysis

What I have so far is:
Let $\epsilon > 0$.  Choose $\delta > 0$ such that $\delta < $ (insert choice of $\epsilon$ here).  Then for $x>0$ and $0<x<\delta$, we have
$\left|{\frac{\sqrt{x^2}}{x}-(-1)}\right|=\left|\frac{\sqrt{x^2}}{x}+1\right|=\left|\frac{x}{x}+1\right|=2$.

I'm pretty sure I did something wrong here.

Comment: If $x\to 0^-$ then you want $-\delta < x<0$.

Comment: That is right. But for $\lim_{x \to 0^-}$ you may want to consider $x < 0$ which gives you $\sqrt{x^2} = -x$...

Comment: [Helpful graph](http://i.imgur.com/2MZTDTw.png)

Answer (score 6):

Hint

Notice that for $x<0$ we have

$$\sqrt{x^2}=|x|=-x$$

Comment: Oh!  I see now!  Thank you!!!

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

As a slightly more complicated alternative to Sami Ben Romdhane's answer, note that
$$\frac{\sqrt{x^2}}{x}= \frac{|x|}{x}= \text{ sgn}(x)$$
where $\text{ sgn}(x)$ is the sign function, defined as $-1$ for $x<0$.